# darle funcion a un button

Tags: javascript

quería darle función a un botón para que aparezca un nuevo usuario; estoy usando esta [API](https://reqres.in/)

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json =>{
    console.log(json.data);
    const markup = json.data.map(el => {
        return `
        <li class="card-container">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="round" src="${el.avatar}">
    
            </div>
             <div class="name-container">
           

                 <span class="firstName">${el.first_name}</span>
               
                 <span class="lastName">${el.last_name}</span>
                
                
             </div> 
             
            </li>
        `
    })
    console.log(markup);
    document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = markup.join('');

})

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const user= document.getElementById('container2');

btn.addEventListener('click',mostrarUser)

function mostrarUser() {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
    .then (res => res.json())
    .then(data=>{
             user.innerHTML= `<li class="card-container">
             <div class="image-container">
               <img class="round" src="${data.avatar}">
     
             </div>
              <div class="name-container">
            
 
                  <span class="firstName">${data.first_name}</span>
                
                  <span class="lastName">${data.last_name}</span>
                 
                 
              </div> 
              
             </li>`
    } )

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Lista de Usuarios</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="container">

      </ul>

    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="btn">Agregar Nuevo Usuario</button>

      <ul class="container2">

      </ul>

    </div>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo que agregarle función al botón y no sale nada. Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta rápida es cambiar esto:

```javascript
const user= document.getElementById('container2');
```

por esto:

```javascript
const user= document.querySelector('.container2');
```

porque `container2` no es un **id**, sino una clase, y para seleccionar la primera coincidencia de clase en el DOM se utiliza `querySelector`.

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json =>{
    console.log(json.data);
    const markup = json.data.map(el => {
        return `
        <li class="card-container">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="round" src="${el.avatar}">
    
            </div>
             <div class="name-container">
           

                 <span class="firstName">${el.first_name}</span>
               
                 <span class="lastName">${el.last_name}</span>
                
                
             </div> 
             
            </li>
        `
    })
    console.log(markup);
    document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = markup.join('');

})

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const user= document.querySelector('.container2');

btn.addEventListener('click',mostrarUser)

function mostrarUser() {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
    .then (res => res.json())
    .then(data=>{
             user.innerHTML= `<li class="card-container">
             <div class="image-container">
               <img class="round" src="${data.avatar}">
     
             </div>
              <div class="name-container">
            
 
                  <span class="firstName">${data.first_name}</span>
                
                  <span class="lastName">${data.last_name}</span>
                 
                 
              </div> 
              
             </li>`
    } )

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Lista de Usuarios</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="container">

      </ul>

    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="btn">Agregar Nuevo Usuario</button>

      <ul class="container2">

      </ul>

    </div>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Pero no me voy a quedar ahí, porque luego verás que te da resultados inesperados mostrando `undefined` al agregar el elemento.

Eso se debe a que la API te esta devolviendo un array de objetos, y no solo uno, y estas usando una sintaxis como si solo hubiera uno al llamar a sus datos.

Reescribiendo tu código para solucionar ese error y otros, yo lo hubiera hecho así para ir agregando usuarios uno a uno, en lugar de solo uno:

```js
const userList = document.querySelector('.container');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let userIndex = 0

fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    // console.log(json.data);
    const markup = json.data.map(el => {
      return `
        <li class="card-container">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="round" src="${el.avatar}">
            </div>
             <div class="name-container">
                 <span class="firstName">${el.first_name}</span>
                 <span class="lastName">${el.last_name}</span>
             </div> 
            </li>
        `
    })
    // console.log(markup);
    userList.innerHTML = markup.join('');
  })

btn.addEventListener('click', mostrarUser)

function mostrarUser() {
  fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      userList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li class="card-container">
             <div class="image-container">
               <img class="round" src="${json.data[userIndex].avatar}">
             </div>
              <div class="name-container">
                  <span class="firstName">${json.data[userIndex].first_name}</span>
                  <span class="lastName">${json.data[userIndex].last_name}</span>
              </div> 
             </li>`)
      userIndex++
      if (userIndex == 6) {
        btn.innerText = "No hay más usuarios"
        btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }

    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Lista de Usuarios</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="container">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="btn">Agregar Nuevo Usuario</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```